# Migration token from AuthSub to OAuth2

Tags: google-oauth, authsub

Recently, AuthSub died...?

Is it possible to migration from session_token of Authsub to refresh_token of OAuth2 ?

Please tell me how to do it if possible.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a failing request?

Answer (score 2):

Its still supported, but is failing for us as well (and others if search twitter for it).  I'm wondering if Google is experience a technical issue with AuthSub or if they made a change (e.g. patch/release) earlier this week that is causing the issues?

We see it working for some Google accounts and fail for others - starting on Dec 10/11.  So, its not impacting every Google account.

---

We are currently not capturing the outgoing requests to google. We are using the library gdata-calendar-1.0.jar to make google calendar api calls using AuthSub and the library is throwing an exception with the exception message "Unknown authorization header". This worked perfectly up until Dec 10/11th or so for all of our users.

What is strange is now the same calls do work for certain gmail accounts but not for others.

In our testing we are seeing that turning off the enhanced security in our web application results in the warning displayed to the user on the Google Authorization page but makes the connection work for the accounts that are failing.

Here are the api calls we are making:

```
AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken to connect to the google account
CalendarService.query to get events
CalendarService.insert to insert events in calendar
CalendarService.getFeed to get the calendars
```

---

Comment: Can you provide a sample of a failing request?

Comment: I have contacted the Calendar team regarding this issue. Will follow up in this thread as soon as I get a response.

Answer (score 0):

[AuthSub](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthSub) is still supported by Google as per Google's [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/accounts/terms).

As for a migration path to OAuth2, currently there is none.